# Why cant I load Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10.

Tags: bootloader

Every time i try burn onto disk or usb, it comes back with errors or missing files, i really want to use Ubuntu, but this keeps happening everytime, please help!!

Comment: Did you try to download a new iso? Maybe yurs is currupted.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a corrupted download. Do a md5sum check on the iso and make sure it matches the hashes [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the minimal Cd. It is approximately 35MB in size. It will download the missing packages after the core of Ubuntu is installed. The minimal CD can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). I don't know why your disks are missing files, but if it is occurring during the download or while burning the disks, a smaller iso will reduce the risk of it happening. Just a suggestion. However, when you go to install Ubuntu, make sure you have a good internet connect because it will download quite a bit.